# Mariadb configure alloted memory

Tags: mariadb

I want to allocate more memory to my MariaDB server but I am having difficulties in locating the right my.cnf file.

Basically I want to edit the innodb_buffer_pool_size

This is the content of the my.cnf file in /etc/my.cnf

```
 [mysqld]
    bind-address = ::
    skip_name_resolve
    local-infile=0
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
    symbolic-links=0
    # Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
    # If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
    # customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
    # instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

    [mysqld_safe]
    log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
    pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

    #
    # include all files from the config directory
    !includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

So I proceeded to check the files in /etc/my.cnf.d for the innodb_buffer_pool_size value, but most of the files are almost empty.

Should I just add the string with the value that I prefer? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Using Plesk 17.5.3 #18 CentOS 7 and MariaDB 10.1.25

Hope someone can help me out on this one.

I added the inno_db_buffer_size to my.cnf as suggested, but whe

Hi, I adjusted the value and restarted the service, but when I run:
https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl
It gives me the following output:

Hi, I adjusted the value and restarted the service, but when i run:
https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl
It gives me the following output:

```
    Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
    Performance should be activated for better diagnostics
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    thread_cache_size (start at 4)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 139M) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances (=1)
```

It seems to me that even though I adjusted the value, it's not reflected.
How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay that you do not see the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Most of MySQL parameters are not defined in `/etc/my.cnf` and database server uses the default ones. For `innodb_buffer_pool_size` it is 128M.
To set this value differ just define it in `[mysqld]` of `/etc/my.cnf`. For example `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I adjusted it, but it doesn't reflect, please see the additions in my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should restart the database server after updating `/etc/my.cnf`. To check what value is set login to database server and run `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024;`

Comment: I even restarted the whole server just to be sure, but no change.
I checked all .cnf files in etc/my.cnf.d but the innodb_buffer_pool_size is only stated in /etc/my.cnf (since I put it there) as:
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G

Comment: Thanks! I found out what went wrong, I added it to the wrong section in the my.cnf file. It should be under [mysqld] I overlooked it in the file.